# Scala XML parsing with Xpath

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using the below command to extract the value from "NAME" field. I have got the results but need it in a different way.

```
mapVal.map(x => (x \\ "ALERT" \\"property" \\"name")text)
```

**sampleoutput** : stackoverflowstackoverflowquery

**Expected output** : separate results in next line

line 1 : stackoverflow

line 2 : stackoverflow

line 3 : query

How can i read nodeseq one by one?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the XML that produces these results

Answer (score 1):

If your XML is structured like what I show here, the subsequent code does what you want:

```
import scala.language.postfixOps
import scala.xml._
val xmlstr =
"""
<root>
  <ALERT>
    <property>
      <name>stackoverflow</name>
      <value>rox</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>stackoverflow</name>
      <value></value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>query</name>
    </property>
  </ALERT>
</root>
"""
val mapVal = XML.loadString(xmlstr)
val names = {
  val alerts     = (mapVal \\ "ALERT")
  val properties = (alerts \\"property")
  (properties \\"name")
}
for( name <- names ){
  printf("[%s]\n",name.text)
}
```

You could use scala.xml literals, but since scala.xml is deprecated, you might want to consider using a different xml library.

I've been experimenting with [Yaidom](https://github.com/dvreeze/yaidom) for a couple of days now.  It's an active project as of one month ago, unlike many other scala xml alternatives.

Another choice might be [RaptureXML](https://github.com/ZaBlanc/RaptureXML), although I haven't found any usage examples yet.

Here's the equivalent code using yaidom:

```
import eu.cdevreeze.yaidom.simple.Elem
val xmlstr =
"""
<root>
  <ALERT>
    <property>
      <name>stackoverflow</name>
      <value>rox</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>stackoverflow</name>
      <value></value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>query</name>
    </property>
  </ALERT>
</root>
"""
val mapVal = fromString(xmlstr)
val names = {
  val alerts     = (mapVal \\ ( _.localName == "ALERT" ))
  val properties = alerts.flatMap { a => (a \\ ( _.localName == "property")) }
  properties.flatMap { p => ( p \\ ( _.localName == "name")) }
}
for( name <- names ){
  printf("[%s]\n",name.text)
}

def fromString(str:String) = {
  import java.{ io => jio }
  domParser.parse(new jio.ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes("utf-8"))).documentElement
}
import eu.cdevreeze.yaidom.parse.DocumentParserUsingDom
lazy val domParser = DocumentParserUsingDom.newInstance
```

BTW, the above is working code, tested under scala 2.11.7.  It also seems to work with 2.12.0-M3 using the 2.11.7 scala.xml library (it's not guaranteed to be binary compatible, but seems to work for this example).